# code style over files modified in current commit

Tags: git, coding-style, continuous-integration

I like to use tools to check code style like [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) (Python) or [jshint](http://jshint.com/) (Javascript).

In a Javascript example, I can use the following command to check every `.js` file in the Git repo:

```
jshint $(git ls-files | grep .js$ )
```

I would like to check the code style in the server of continuous integration, but only in the last modified files.

How I can check only the files modified in the current commit?

#### EDIT

With

```
 git status --porcelain | sed s/^...//
```

I can get the name of modified files without commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the files modified in the last commit should probably be

```
git diff HEAD^ --name-only --diff-filter=AM
```

you then call your linters on those names as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I find useful [it article](http://www.eriwen.com/tools/continuous-integration-for-javascript/) for my needs. Also see [nice comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15757989/3604050) about pre-commit jshint