# pre-commit hook with lint

Tags: git, angular-cli, lint, tslint

I'm trying to add precommit-hook to my project, this is my script section on package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "lint": "npm run lint:sass && npm run lint:js",
    "lint:js": "ng lint",
    "lint:sass": "sass-lint src/**/*.scss -v -q"
}...
"pre-commit": [
    "lint"
],
```

If I only execute this line:

> npm run lint:sass && npm run lint:js

Everything works great, but when I'm trying to add [precommit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/precommit-hook) my terminal just freeze on:

> git commit -m "Testing"
>
> running lint...

Comment: perhaps you could use 'husky': https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky

Comment: @Philippe is not even take the 'precommit' :( I've uninstall 'precommit-hook' without any luck :(